# Next.js toggle display of a div tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

## Code

```
export default function Header(){
  let showMe = false;
  function toggle(){
    showMe = !showMe;
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle Subjects</button>
      {/*The bottom code should toggle on and off when the button is pressed*/}
      <div style={{
        display: showMe?"block":"none"
      }}>
        This should toggle my display
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

---

## Expectation

The `div` tag should toggle in visibility (For example, if I clicked on the button once, the div tag should show up, and if I clicked on it again it would be hidden and so on).

---

## Reality

It appears the variable `showMe` changes however the `div` tag does not follow with the updates and remains hidden.

**NOTE: I am using next.js if that changes anything.**

Comment: You need to you useState for that (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`showMe` needs to be a state variable so that React knows to rerender the component when `showMe` changes. I'd read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

The code below should work (note how `showMe` is replaced with a call to `useState`).

```
export default function Header(){
  const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);
  function toggle(){
    setShowMe(!showMe);
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={toggle}>Toggle Subjects</button>
      {/*The bottom code should toggle on and off when the button is pressed*/}
      <div style={{
        display: showMe?"block":"none"
      }}>
        This should toggle my display
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The bracket notation `const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);` is Array Destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

`useState` returns an array of length 2. Using array destructuring, we set the first element of the returned array to `showMe` and the second element of the returned array to `setShowMe`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am a bit confused by the notation of `[showMe, setShowMe]` the two brackets however

Comment: That's array destructuring: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Quick question, why do I have to do `import { useState } from "react";` instead of `import useState from "react";` to use `useState`?

Comment: `react`'s default export is an object that we name `React` when we do `import React from "react"`. `React` has a property `useState` so we could have used `React.useState(false)` if we wanted. I'd look at this for more details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: ahh ok. So if I did `import React from 'react';` I would have to do `React.useState`. Ok I got it now I think. Thanks!