# Next.js show/hide divs on buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hide, next.js, show

I am trying to show and hide divs on buttons in Next JS.

This post helped me a lot:
[Next.js toggle display of a div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60939606/next-js-toggle-display-of-a-div-tag/60939664#60939664)

I used this solution using useState in my case and it works perfectly. The difference is that I have many buttons and each of them supposes to show different div and hide active div.

This is what I am trying to achieve
https://codepen.io/CthuKi/pen/YqZvRv

```
export default function Header(){
    const [showMe, setShowMe] = useState(false);
    function toggle(){
    setShowMe(!showMe);
}

      return (
        <>
          <button onClick={toggle}>Button 1</button>
          <button onClick={toggle}>Button 2</button>
          <button onClick={toggle}>Button 3</button>
       <div>
          <div style={{display: showMe?"block":"none"}}>
            Show this div on button 1 and hide other active
          </div>
          <div style={{display: showMe?"block":"none"}}>
            Show on button 2 and hide other active
          </div>
          <div style={{display: showMe?"block":"none" }}>
            Show on button 3 and hide other active
          </div>
         </div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

I will appreciate any help

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be to have multiple `toggle` functions to toggle multiple `div`s. But there is a better way, create only one state variable `showAll` and one function `toggleAll` to show all the content.

To toggle one button to show specific content, create an array of data that you want to show, and just change the index to show the current data from the array.

For example, see the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-l7w16?file=/App.js:0-1119) for demo

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(["hello", "hi there", "holla"]);

  const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(false);
  const [currentIdx, setCurrentIdx] = useState(0);
  const [showCurrent, setShowCurrent] = useState(false);

  const toggleAll = () => {
    setShowAll(val => !val);
    setShowCurrent(false);
  };

  const toggleCurrent = () => {
    if (!showCurrent) {
      setShowCurrent(true);
      setShowAll(false);
      return;
    }
  };

  const setCurrent = index => {
    setCurrentIdx(index);
    toggleCurrent();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggleAll}>{showAll ? "Hide All" : "Show All"}</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCurrent(0)}>First</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCurrent(1)}>Second</button>
        <button onClick={() => setCurrent(2)}>Third</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        {showAll && data.map((el, i) => <p key={`content-${i}`}>{el}</p>)}
      </div>

      {showCurrent ? <div>{data[currentIdx]}</div> : null}
    </div>
  );
};
```